# Keeping track of an object instance over fragment life-cycle

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, singleton

I have a very specific problem with an android Fragment. I've read a bunch about how to store data persistently, but no solution quite matches my needs.

I have a custom class RpgChar (representing an RPG character with it's stats) and want to write a Fragment to display one of those stats (say, current health points). Which stats (or even actions) to display should be flexible, so Fragments are the way to go. The TextView (or whatever) in the Fragment has to be linked to the corresponding field in RpgChar. Easy to do with PropertyChangeListeners.

Now the trouble is that Fragments get destroyed and constructed constantly. Creating the RpgChar instance is done by the activity. I can of course pass it to the Fragment initially, but how do I keep track of it?

The first solution pointed out everywhere is to put it into the Bundle. First of, RpgChar does file handling, so as far as I know making it Serializable or Parcelable is a real hassle. Also, if a new character is loaded, the change has to be done manually for every Fragment.

Second idea of mine is to make RpgChar singleton-like. I already have a factory class RpgChars with static factory methods. I could have this class keep track of one RpgChar instance. Either I make it a true singleton, which is annoying because I have to modify an existing instance instead of simply creating a new one. Or I have it create new instances. Easier to do, but I might have references to the old character lying around somewhere.

I would greatly appreciate any pros or cons on the above ideas or entirely new ones. I am looking for a solution that is safe in the sense that I don't have much to do to make sure every fragment has the right instance to track. At the same time I don't like to blow up my code too much. Might even be there is a standard practice I'm not aware of for these situations?

PS: If needed I will provide some code examples later, for now I will google some more and get drunk. :)

Comment: why do you need fragments for that?

Comment: Well, depending on the details of the character I want to display different parts of the interface. For example, only show mana for mages or something like that. Sounds like a job for Fragments, or do you have a different idea?

Comment: Im biased and dont like fragments very much (unlike 99% folks here)

Comment: The fragment is nothing like a mini activity (lifecycle) with own view, nothig more

Comment: Well, I see where you're coming from. The alternative would be to construct everything "by hand" in the main activity. Making Views visible/invisible, adding Listeners, etc. . With a fragment, I just give it the RpgChar and a String with the stat to display, that's it. Since there are many similar stats to show, it saves a lot of effort. I can also reuse them over different Activities.

Comment: Do the same with a custom view, i dont see any difference...

Comment: btw do you know square guys? known for dagger, otto, picasso, okhttp, retrofit... this is what they think about fragments: http://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html

Comment: Good link, thanks a lot. That pretty much solves all my issues. I was going the way Google points you in their guides. By making the app based on one Activity only, by using Views and Presenters instead of Fragments I have no problems anymore. Only one Activity means two-way communication is easier, and by using Views I have control over their life-cycle. Please make your comment into an answer so I can accept it. :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped,  "my lord,  one more evangelized" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> First of, RpgChar does file handling, so as far as I know making it Serializable or Parcelable is a real hassle

Well, keep in mind the SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) here. An RpgChar object shouldn't be doing anything else but representing what is absolutely necessary for an Rpg character. File handling is a different concern. What you could (and probably, should) do is to create another class, like RpgCharHandler (or so), which sole responsibility is to save / load an RpgChar object. Not only this is a more correct approach, but also you win that you don't have implement Serializable or Parcelable on your RpgChar object.

I certainly wouldn't reccommend the singleton pattern here. You already wrote some of the cons. Also, depending on what references your class holds, it can lead to memory leaks if those references (related to anything like Views, Activities) are kept alive after Android tries to destroy the activity they belonged to.

Now what you can also do is not having any Fragments at all for what you want to do with them (I base this on your comment below your original post). Rather, if you only want some visible / invisible elements you can  fall back to toggling their visibility programmatically. Of course you lose some flexibility here, but if it's really only a small number of effected elements, it's a viable alternative.